Facebook Long Lived Page Access Token expires after 60 days despite the doc say it's permanent
Facebook says a page long lived access token will never expired but somehow mine got expired today after 60 days. The error message says: Error validating access token: Session has expired ....

If the token does expire, is there a way to repeatedly refresh the page token after a certain period?
